# How can I prevent Excel from opening a userform when opened from a macro in Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to create a macro in outlook that opens a file in excel and runs a procedure from that file. This code does that beautifully...

```
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
Dim ExWbk As Workbook
Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Control Verification\Controls Verification Updated.xlsm")
ExApp.Visible = False

ExWbk.Application.Run "Module1.Email_All"

ExWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

When someone opens this workbook normally I have a `userform` automatically display to allow the user to select different things, BUT when I open it from Outlook I don't want this `userform` to display.

I only need access to a different procedure in the userform that doesn't require any selections. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use a global boolean to determine whether or not you want the userform to display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Work with [Application.EnableEvents Property for disabling the Events before you open the workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-enableevents-property-excel)*

*Example*

> ```
> ExApp.EnableEvents = False 
> ExApp.Workbooks.Open("Path") ' < Your code here
> ExApp.EnableEvents = True
> ```