# Is there any way ro get bacck to hidden Workbook from Userform Excel VBA

Tags: excel, userform

I created a Userform and assigned a macro to it so that when the workbook opens, the form appears and the workbook itself is hidden. But the whole comedy is that I assigned a macro to the "X" button, which closes both the book and the form, and I need to complete the macro and therefore I have a question: is there a way to return the hidden book and the BWA editor?

Comment: You can open a book with events disabled by hitting `Shift + Open`. See [here](https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/preventopenevent.asp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50747573/4539709